# Visual Studio 2010 Debugger problem - unregistered Error?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having some problems with Visual Studio 2010's **debugger** when using the unit-test debugging mode.

When ever I hit a breakpoint in a test all the object data is replaced with question marks and it tells me "Child could not be evaluated". Shortly after, it will **abort** debugging-mode by it self and ignore any futher break points. 
There is not shown any error, but under summary you can read:

**Test host process exited unexpectedly.**

I can't find any useful information about this error.

There is no problem debugging outside the test or when stepping through (/stepping into) the test. If I place a breakpoint for every line, it will show me the data most of the times. 
If there is not a breakpoint for EVERY line that is connected to modification of the object the test will abort.

The data has been shown earlier without problem, and yes all references are available and up to date.

*Have anybody experienced a simular problem? ... And hopefully found a solution?*

**This is what I've tried so far:**

- Rebuildning and cleaning the solution.
- closing visual studio + reboot system
- installed VS10 Service Pack 1
- reinstalled Visual Studio 10
- tested on VS10 Ultimate and Premium
- Removing and regenerating solutions files
- Removing all break points
- TraceAndTestImpact/Local.testsettings: Test Timeout > timeout and abort set to 30 minuts.
- TraceAndTestImpact/Local.testsettings: Unit Test >assemblie folders defined
- TraceAndTestImpact/Local.testsettings: Deployment > Enable deplyment - directories and files

**System information**
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

**Additional information:**

- When stepping through the code, the data is visible.
- The tests I'm running is NOT failing. If no breakpoint are sat they passes.
- If I place the breakpoint earlier in the the code, the test just aborts there.
- The only visible runtime object information is the count and it's displayed like this: "Count = 0x00000001"
- Additional to this problem, the debugger is generally "bugging". When I remove break points they come back! Some break points are invisible until the time of debugging. Breakpoints placed before the problem started can't be removed and is still working fine.

**ANY suggestions are more then welcome.** I have no idea what to try next.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What exactly are you evaluating when hthis happens?  Is it a LINQ query?

Comment: No LINQ. The code is running fine and the test is parsing as long as I'm not using the breakpoints to tjeck the data.

Comment: There is no specifict kind of code I'm evaluating, it accoures at any point in the code where I place a new breakpoint.